# Пакетное сжатие изображений и добавления вотермарок

Tags: jpeg, сжатие

Нужна программа для оптимального пакетного сжатия jpeg изображений под веб, которая помимо прочего способна добавлять в центр изображения png вотермарку. Видел как делают подобное в галпе, возможно кто-то подскажет подобное ПО или как это реализовать.

Comment: _Видел как делают подобное в галпе_  Ну вот вы уже ответили на свой вопрос, копайте в этом направлении. P.S. Минификация - https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-imagemin  Вотермарк - https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watermark

Comment: Вот тут то и проблема, не очень понимаю как это всё автоматизировать, поэтому и ищи готовое решение\софт